# tcp: recomposing data at the end

Tags: tcp

How do TCP knows which is the last packet of a large file (that was segmented by tcp) in the scenario that the connection is kept-established. (like ftp or sending mp3 on yahoo messenger)

I mean how does it know which packet carries data of one.mp3 and which packet carries data of another.mp3 ??

Anyone ?

Thank you

Comment: Random comment: [`SCTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCTP) solves this by design, pity it's not used more...

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 possible approaches.

- Declare upfront how much data you're going to send. Something like a packet that declares *Sending a message that's 4008 bytes long*
- The second approach is to use a terminating sequence (nastier to process)

So the receiver:

- Tries to read the declared amount or
- Scans for the terminating sequence

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a stream protocol and fragmentation should be transparent to a TCP application. It operates on streams of data, never packets. A stream is assembled to its intended order using the sequence numbers. The sequence of bytes send by application is encapsulated in tcp segments. The stream is recreated on the receiver side before data is delivered to the application.

The IP protocol can do fragmentation.

Each TCP segment goes to the IP layer and may be fragmented there. Segment is reassembled by collecting all of the packets and offset field from the header is used to put it in the right place.

Comment: I know that ... but how does it know which is the last packet that form a file .. ? I don't care about if it is transparent .. now i'm referring to non transparent way

Comment: in my understanding it doesn't know. TCP just sends stream of bytes and don't care what is it. The application have to interpret that stream and divide it into files. It doesn't operate on packets.

Comment: Is the length specified in the header of the protocol (application protocol like ftp / ssh / http) ? But that's very bad cause anyone can modify that headers.